# How do I open the last n files I was working on in vim?

Tags: filesystem

I know that the `:oldfiles` command will show you a history of the files you last had open; but how do I open the last n files in one command...for instance, say I want to open files 0-n in the `:oldfiles` list, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Note: Using `:browse oldfiles` will allow you to pick one from the list, but it doesn't open say the last n files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files listed by `:oldfiles` are also available as a list in [`v:oldfiles`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aoldfiles), so something like:

```
for f in v:oldfiles[:10]
    exec "badd" f
endfor
```

Using an appropriate value instead of 10, of course.